# How to block other IP to use my rtmp-ffmpeg restreamed links?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming

I restream the streams with rtmp-ffmpeg technique, in `etc/nginx/sites-available` i allow my domains to show my stream just like so:

```
server {
    listen   80; 

    #root /var/www/html/; 
    #index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com; 

    location / {
    proxy_redirect off; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

But everyone can play my restreamed links/m3u8 in vlc or another desktop player, the links can be also be restreamed again in `xtream code` or in other `rtmp-ffmpeg` scripts. My `rtmp-ffmpeg` look like so:

```
[program:test]
autorestart=true
command=/usr/bin/ffmpeg -hide_banner -i https://example.com/playlist.m3u8  -c copy -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_flags append_list+delete_segments -hls_list_size 6 -hls_segment_filename '/etc/nginx/hls/test/file%%03d.ts' /etc/nginx/hls/test/playlist.m3u8
```

How can I block other people to restream my streams?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there would be several approaches for authenticated content.

You may use dynamic link for your audience. Maybe you can also try to use `referer` in the `location`

```js
location / {
  valid_referers none blocked example.com www.example.com;
  if ($invalid_referer) { return 404; }

  #Some other stuff
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, where to add this?

Comment: Add into the location you would like to apply the rule. Please I've edited the answer.